# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 : Editing TypeScript files are very slow

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, typescript

We have been using TypeScript in our project since last year with VS 2012. Recently we upgraded to **VS 2013 Pro Update 2** and now if we work on TypeScript the IDE performance is extremely slow (particularly the save file).

Also once I open a TypeScript file the IDE becomes slower for all the files (cshtml, js, cs) in that web project.

I found the following article to improve the performance of VS 2013 but it did not work.

[Why is VS 2013 very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow)

This problem was never there with VS 2012. Is there any workaround for this issue?

**Update**: We now know that the problem is with AnkhSVN plugin that we are using in VS 2013.

https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2506

If we disable this plugin then this problem disappears. But this workaround is not convenient as we still need AnkhSVN to track changes in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the VS 2013 Update 3 RC today and it fixed this issue.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43398

Answer (score 0):

> This problem was never there with VS 2012. Is there any workaround for this issue?

One workaround would be to try disabling the compile on save option for TypeScript. If that helps you might want to investigate some thing like https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

Comment: I dont have compile on save enabled. JavaScripts are produced when I build the project

Comment: perhaps you can modify the project to remove the `<TypeScriptYYY>` entirely to disable any form of build....to isolate the problem to *build*

Comment: I did change every <TypeScriptCompile> to <Content> in my csproj and the problem is still there