# Slow context menu in Visual Studio 2015 on right click folder in web project

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2015

Some of our team who are trialing VS 2015 on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit are seeing this issue:

[Visual Studio 2013 context menus slow only in web application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656896/visual-studio-2013-context-menus-slow-only-in-web-application-project)

When right-clicking a folder (only a folder in a web app project) there is a lengthy delay in rendering the context menu, as well as any dialogs.

Installation details:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00079

Installed Version: Professional

Visual Basic 2015   00322-50050-08414-AA353
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-50050-08414-AA353
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-50050-08414-AA353
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Visual F# 2015 RC   00322-50050-08414-AA353
Microsoft Visual F# 2015 RC

ASP.NET and Web Tools   14.0.20626.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.5
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

GenerateUnitTest   1.0
Generates unit test code for methods in classes under test.

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.1.3   Build 102.0.20150724.141603
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2015 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.0.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
```

We have tried the following:

```
Restarting Visual Studio, and re-opening the solution
Cleaning the solution, and deleting the obj folders.
Recreating the project
Clearing Resharper's Cache
Disabling rich client / hardware graphics acceleration in Options->Environment->General
Disabling Resharper
Deleting all Temporary ASP.Net folders
Deleting the contents of %localappdata%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
Deleting all *.suo user options files
Uninstalling all extensions (Web compiler, Bundler and Minifier)
Probably some other things that I have forgotten.
```

Running process monitor during a right click shows every project reference being processed in a CreateFile/ QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile/CloseFile sequence 4 times, like this:

[image]

Any ideas what is happening here ? The delay is too long to ignore and occurs for the right click and every selection from the context menu.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After we submitted a support request to Microsoft, it turns out the issue was a broken project reference in the Web application project

After removing the reference, the context menus behave normally, without any lag.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue for our team (for anyone wondering where to look for missing reference - it's under project References folder, where will be missing reference icon next to the assembly name)

Answer (score 5):

I have just solved this problem in a different way.

Simply delete the contents of:
C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache

Credit: http://www.geocortex.com/about/blog/archive/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/

Comment: Yes, that is one solution we also tried, along with the other various attempted solutions listed. It didn't work for us, glad it worked for  you.

Comment: Awesome..Worked for me.