# How to solve reference issues in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having an issue with a new project in VS 2015 Community.

The problem is when I try to access the context menu by right-clicking any folder in solution explorer VS hangs for ~20 seconds with further delay for each context menu.

More details:
I use tortoiseGit and git to pull the project and I did not create it. 
The solution has two projects, one library and one WebApp. The problem only happens in the WebApp. The library project is built first and the WebApp has the library as a dependency.

I noticed that there are issues with the references specifically in the WebApp project. Based on this I'm assuming the issue is the same as or similar to another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937856/slow-context-menu-in-visual-studio-2015-on-right-click-folder-in-web-project).

I see that user mentions the problem was solved by removing the references that had issues.

Now my actual question is can I just remove the references, are they not necessary? (e.g. references to System.Collections seem necessary)

Further, I'm quite new to C# and VS so any advice on how to remove references or anything to fix will be appreciated because I seem to keep breaking things by doing it the incorrect way e.g. deleting .dll files and such.

Here is a list of the problem references:

```
System.Collections
System.Collections.Concurrent
System.ComponentModel
System.Diagnostics.Debug
System.Dynamic.Runtime
System.Globalization
System.Linq
System.Linq.Expressions
System.Linq.Queryable
System.ObjectModel
System.Reflection
System.Reflection.Extensions
System.Runtime
System.Runtime.Extensions
System.Text.RegularExpressions
System.Threading
System.Threading.Tasks
```

[Broken references 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FFiM.png)

[Broken references 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7RWK.png)