# Disabling Resharper option that causes VS 2013 to switching tabs slowly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-9.0

While building an ASP.NET MVC application with AngularJS, VS2013 is exhibiting very bad responsiveness when switching between the file-tabs. VS is reacting extremely slow, needing up to three and more seconds loading the file-content by switching the tabs when Resharper is activated.

I am working with .cs, .js, .html and .cshtml files including Razor syntax, etc.

I found out that Resharper was the problem. By disabling Resharper, everything now works perfectly fast. It looks like Resharper is taking ages to analyze these .html, .cshtml and .js files. However, I am currently looking for deactivating the responsible Resharper option which is causing the problem.  Does someone know which option could be responsible for the problem?

I am currently running on Visual Studio (version 12.0.31101.0) and Resharper (version 9.0 Update 1).

Comment: You might be better off contacting Jetbrains directly or using the [ReSharper Support Site](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/home) and asking a question there.

Comment: is it vs2013 community edition? I've had this issue before it may not be your issue but worth checking out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow/26921455#26921455

Easiest thing to try is (temporarily) deleting the contents of `packages.config` and then try switching between files

Comment: @wal I am using vs2013 premium and deleting the content of packages.config has definitely some positive impact on the Performance when Resharper is activated - thanks for that hint!

However, without resharper, task switching is speedy even if the packages.config is full of config-entries.

So it seems the Problem is Kind of located on a combination of resharper and the packages.config.

Did you had resharper installed and activated while experiencing the the Problem?

I think we can tell now that those Impacts with packages.config are not appearing on the vs2013 community Edition only.

Comment: `Did you had resharper installed and activated while experiencing the the Problem? ` Yes. Were you loading a sln file from an existing project? I only experienced this issue with certain vsprojs not all