# Visual Studio takes ages creating a project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have problem with my Visual studio 2013. When I'm trying to create even a simple console application,VS hangs and after a while the message 'Visual studio is busy: Microsoft Visual studio is waiting for internal operation to complete.' shows up.

I have reinstalled Visual Studio but without any luck. I've used ProcMon to check devenv and all the paths it shows, have to do with Android Studio.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming problem (assuming you did not *write* VS 2013). Perhaps better asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I've seen similar questions on this site but not with the answer to my specific problem so I figured it was OK to ask here

Comment: Try disabling the Android Studio add-in. Generally, when Visual Studio is misbehaving, it's usually best to disable Extensions/Add-ins one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: True: [help/on-topic] says ".. software tools commonly used by programmers" – but I suspect it's Just Your System, and if the same happens with other software as well, Super User users may have a solution or hints for you.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru There doesn't seem to be an Android Studio add-in. The Add-in manager is completely empty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why VS 2013 is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow)

Answer (score 2):

I 'solved' the problem by accident. I disabled Source Control and for some reason, VS started working again. I know it's not an ideal solution but works just fine when you need VS urgently.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if Visual Studio is one of those programs. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe even after uninstalling, Visual Studio keeps some files in the registry from your previous installation and the AppData folder. You might want to clear those.

- Close Visual Studio (if you haven’t already).
- Open the registry editor (regedit.exe)
- Delete the
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio{version}
- Delete the
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio{version}_Config
- Delete the %USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio{version}
  directory.

> ```
> Use {version}=10.0 for Visual Studio 2010
> Use {version}=11.0 for Visual Studio 2012
> Use {version}=12.0 for Visual Studio 2013
> ```

Hope this helps

Comment: For your information it is not possible to store files in the registry, only references to them.