# Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 is extremely slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio-2013

I have read other articles about performance issues in VS especially [Why VS 2013 is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow), and have performed every advice in this article, but nothing has changed. My VS Studio is running quickly when I am developing a Windows Application. But when I am working on a Web MVC Solution, it is extremely slow. Even simple typing is performed with delay and not only debuging etc.
How can I solve this issue? I have done the following steps:
1. Disabled the plugins (Git...)
2. Cleaned the cache and temporary files
3. Disabled Codelens
4. Disabled synchronization over multiple machines
5. Disabled the hardware graphic accelerations
But nothing has changed and even if I create a new MVC solution, the problem exists and even typing is performed with delay.

Comment: Disable all of your addons and extensions.  Start Visual Studio with the `/log` parameter and examine the logged output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem. You have to run the  [Update 4 RTM](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-update4-rtm-vs) for VS 2013. After that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the /Log (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) or check some tutorials (https://www.google.com/search?q=speed+up+visual+studio+2013). As a final resort you could try a fresh reinstall.