# My Visual studio 2013 typing and scrolling is slow. What Can i do?

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013, scroll, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm Currently working on Visual studio 2013 (MVC 5). Since few days I'm getting a problem with typing and scrolling, database is connecting slow. But all working fine but slowly.

**Problems:**

1. When typing a letter that keyword display taking long time and some
   times not displayed.
2. Scrolling the solution explorer does not response correctly.
3. Connect the Database is not showing the connection string.

I searched on the internet and found smooth scroll plugin. After installing that it worked for some hours only after that getting same problem

Comment: That may be a Visual Studio extension (package, addin, etc.). Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [**Visual Studio 2013 Update 5**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3021976) which will play an important role here you can also check other solutions listed below.

For smooth scrolling you could try the below [**steps**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2204073-make-editing-typing-scrolling-more-responsive) :

1. For smooth scrolling install [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5fcc21b1-2c9b-4768-a5da-e309811d6b9e) extension
2. In VS Go Tools > Environment > General. 
   My Install had the "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" checked which was using software-accelerated rendering. I unchecked this and checked "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available".
3. Restart VS

**Slow building, debugging, navigating  ?**

**[Why is VS 2013 very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow)**

More references :

[**MSDN**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/237b9278-c243-440c-adcc-0c64abe92607/visual-studio-2012-sp2-is-slow-when-typing-and-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check two things: CPU load and drive load. Open the Task Manager and observe the CPU load to determine if the problem is due to the CPU is being overloaded. Watch the HDD LED to see if it flashing rapidly or on and solid to see if the problem is due to the hard-drive is being thrashed (and thus overloaded). Both can cause this symptom. If you find either to be the case, then your next step is to figure out why the system is being burdened.

if 0% CPU and 0% disk. But any text editing heavily lags? Must be due to some sort of plugin or something. I know the CodeLens, Insights, and Microsoft Git have had issues reported with slow IDE response.

Also try disabling Synchronized Settings in VS. Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment-Synchronized Settings and remove this option by un-checking the check box.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Visual Studio get working normally.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx